# Get WooCommerce coupons by email restrictions using REST API

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

As mentioned in the title, I am trying to access the WooCommerce coupons list by email restrictions to use it in my app.

However I did access the coupons list successfully but i am not being able to get it by email not by code.

Now I tried using **Postman** to get it like this:

```
domain.com/wp-json/wc/v2/coupons?email_restrictions=[email@gmail.com]
```

But it didn't work.

Here is a coupon on my api:

```
{
    "id": 2045,
    "code": "coupon_xaqx0uyw",
    "amount": "5.00",
    "date_created": "2019-03-09T16:38:20",
    "date_created_gmt": "2019-03-09T16:38:20",
    "date_modified": "2019-03-09T16:38:20",
    "date_modified_gmt": "2019-03-09T16:38:20",
    "discount_type": "percent",
    "description": "",
    "date_expires": "2020-03-08T00:00:00",
    "date_expires_gmt": "2020-03-08T00:00:00",
    "usage_count": 0,
    "individual_use": true,
    "product_ids": [],
    "excluded_product_ids": [],
    "usage_limit": 1,
    "usage_limit_per_user": null,
    "limit_usage_to_x_items": null,
    "free_shipping": false,
    "product_categories": [],
    "excluded_product_categories": [],
    "exclude_sale_items": true,
    "minimum_amount": "100.00",
    "maximum_amount": "0.00",
    "email_restrictions": [
        "email@gmail.com"
    ],
    "used_by": [],
    "meta_data": [
        {
            "id": 8482,
            "key": "coupon_user_id",
            "value": "7"
        },
        {
            "id": 8487,
            "key": "sumo_coupon",
            "value": "yes"
        },
        {
            "id": 8488,
            "key": "expire_status",
            "value": "1"
        },
        {
            "id": 8493,
            "key": "action_type",
            "value": "signup"
        },
        {
            "id": 8495,
            "key": "sumo_coupon_check",
            "value": "yes"
        },
        {
            "id": 8496,
            "key": "sumo_coupon_code_sc",
            "value": "INONE_xaqx0uyw"
        }
    ],
    "_links": {
        "self": [
            {
                "href": "https://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/coupons/2045"
            }
        ],
        "collection": [
            {
                "href": "https://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v2/coupons"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: any luck with this?

Comment: did you get your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar situation now. The email-address for which a coupon is limited, is saved in the post_meta field "customer_email". Normally you could call get_posts() and use a meta_key/meta_value combination.

The problem here was that the customer email is stored as a serialized value in the database. this is the reason why the "normal" key-value combination is not working.

I solved this with the following get_posts call:

```
$coupons = get_posts(array(
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'post_type'         => 'shop_coupon',
            'post_status'       => 'publish',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key'       => 'customer_email',
                    'value'     => 'my@email.com',
                    'compare'   => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        ));
```

performance-wise it is for sure not the best solution but in my opinion it is adequate for a simple approach.